# Add .wav metadata in Kid3 on Ubuntu

Tags: wav, metadata

I've downloaded Kid3 to add metadata to a bunch of .wav files. While Kid3 recognizes .wav files (in opposition to EasyTag) and editing data was done very quickly, I was struggling visualizing the metadata in my file browser or in Rhythmbox.

Can anybody please tell:

- What is the problem here? Are Ubuntu file system and Kid3 using different metadata systems?
- How to make the Kid3 metadata changes visible in the file system and in Rhythmbox?

Note: I've already restarted Ubuntu in order to make sure that it is not a caching issue.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/kid3/discussion/241228/thread/6dd445de/ ?

Comment: That's a very useful link for issues like this one. Might help in several cases. Except, It didn't work for my Ubuntu 14.04. with Rhythmbox. Would recommend to make this comment a possible solution anyway.

Comment: The combo ID3 tags + WAV is quite uncommon. An alternative might be to losslessely convert your wav files to flac. Not sure wether rythmbox does support ID3 tags in flac containers.

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems that it doesn't solve the OP issue, there's a thread on Kid3 discussion forum that is titled :

[Tagging of WAV issue - Music players are unable to read the tags of WAV](https://sourceforge.net/p/kid3/discussion/241228/thread/6dd445de/)

Here's an excerpt :

> - Support for RIFF INFO chunks in WAV files seems to be more common than ID3v2 tags, so you should try if RIFF INFO works with your
>     player. Such tags can be created using the "Tag 3" section of WAV
>     files.
> - By default, Kid3 uses IPRT for the track number field in RIFF INFO chunks. Some players use ITRK instead. You can set which is used in
>     "Track number field name" in the "Tags/Tag 3" tab of the preferences.
> - Some players support ID3v2 tags in WAV files, but they expect them to be in a chunk with name "id3 " (lowercase) whereas Kid3 uses "ID3 "
>     (uppercase) by default. You can set this in "WAV files with lowercase
>     id3 chunk", which is in the ID3v2 section of the "Tags/Tag 2" tab of
>     the preferences.
> - Some players support ID3v2 tags in WAV files, but only ID3v2.3.0, and not ID3v2.4.0. Before version 3.4.3, Kid3 always used ID3v2.4.0 in
>     WAV files, but now the setting "Version used for new tags", which is
>     in the ID3v2 section of the "Tags/Tag 2" tab of the preferences, is
>     respected for WAV files too.